# Definition of Formally Smooth from Stack Project

Tags: category-theory, schemes, affine-schemes

[image]

$T, T'$ are affine schemes. What is meant by $F\leftarrow T$ (or $G \leftarrow T')$

Comment: Here $T$ and $T'$ represents the functors $\text{Hom}(\cdot , T),$ and $\text{Hom}(\cdot , T')$  respectively. This identification is due to Yoneda Lemma. With respect to the above identification $F \leftarrow T'$ (or $G \leftarrow T$) are transformations between functors.

Comment: @Krish When giving an answer, use the answer box ! It gives you the possibility to get upvoted, but mainly it gives the opportunity to the OP to accept it (so the question is answered). Last but not least, it is more visible for the visitor reaching this page after a search.